# Change Title Format on Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid, page-title

I would like to ask if how to change the title format for Tag Page on Shopify?
I could see that the code for the title is like this:

```
  <title>
  {{ page_title }}{% if current_tags %}{% assign meta_tags = current_tags | join: ', ' %} &ndash; {{ 'general.meta.tags' | t: tags: meta_tags }}{% endif %}{% if current_page != 1 %} &ndash; {{ 'general.meta.page' | t: page: current_page }}{% endif %}{% unless page_title contains shop.name %} &ndash; {{ shop.name }}{% endunless %}
  </title>
```

this code returns this title for example the Tag is "Star Wars Aircrafts" from the Collection "Star Wars Canvas Art":

```
Star Wars Canvas Art | Domain.com - Tagged "Star Wars Aircrafts" - Shop Name
```

all I want is to simplify it to:

```
Star Wars Aircrafts | Star Wars Canvas Art | Domain.com
```

**Note: All I want is to apply this to Page Created by Tags.**

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
      {% if current_tags %}
      <title>
      {% assign meta_tags = current_tags | join: ', ' %}{{ meta_tags }} | {{ collection.title }} | {{ shop.domain }}
      {% endif %}
      {% if current_page != 1 %} &ndash; {{ 'general.meta.page' | t: page: current_page }}{% endif %}
      </title>
      {% else %}
-- regular title code
      {% endif %}
```

Comment: Hello Scott. I tried some code on the title and I did come up with the right one. I just check if we got same code but it isn't. Thanks for answering btw.